# proving a sequence is increasing defined by a recurrence relation.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Given the recurrence relation $b_{1}=0$ and $$3b_{n+1} = \frac{b_{n}}{12} + \sqrt{\frac{17+b_{n}^{2}}{12}}$$

Show that this recurrence relation is increasing.

Note $36b_{n+1} = b_{n} + \sqrt{204+12b_{n}^{2}}$

So I have started as such:

I have found and proven $0\le b_{n}<1, \quad \forall n\ge1$. Thus

\begin{align}
36b_{n+1} - 36b_{n} &= \sqrt{204+12b_{n}^{2}} - 35b_{n} \\
&= \frac{204+12b_{n}^{2}-1225b_{n}^{2}}{\sqrt{204+12b_{n}^{2}} + 35b_{n}} \\
&= \frac{204-1213b_{n}^{2}}{\sqrt{204+12b_{n}^{2}} + 35b_{n}}
\end{align}

But this is only increasing if $204-1213b_{n}^{2}>0 \iff b_{n}^{2} < 204/1213 \iff -\sqrt{204/1213}<b_{n}<\sqrt{204/1213}$. I know $0\le b_{n}<1$ but nothing more. What can I do?

Comment: To be clear, you want to show that the sequence $b_n$ is increasing. It's meaningless to say a relation is increasing.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, will edit accordingly.

Comment: Isn't $b_n\geq 0$ true for each $n$ as well?

Comment: Yes, that too, so $0\le b_{n}<1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the inequality $f(x)=\frac{x}{36}+\sqrt{\frac{17+x^2}{108}}>x, x>0$, after a little bit rearrangement you get $x<\sqrt{\frac{204}{1213}}=c$, $c$ is also a solution of $f(x)=x$. It remains to prove every term is positive and less than $c$. Notice when $x>0$, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing so if $0<a<c$ we have $f(a)<f(c)=c$, by induction it's easy to show every term is less than $c$.